# Best way to merge two DataTables sorted, without duplicate rows? (C#)

Tags: c#, join, merge, datatable

I have two DataTables (DataTableA and DataTableB) like following: (Assume that each line is each DataRow. Also I added an underscore just to make it look nice. Underscores aren't included in the actual data.

**DataTableA**

```
CategoryA | *blank* | *blank* | *blank* | ... 
Michael __|  24  __ | _31    _| _ 21_   | ... 
Tony  ____| _29  __ | _28    _| _ 19_   | ... 
CategoryB | *blank* | *blank* | *blank* | ... 
John  ____| _12  __ | _31    _| _ 25_   | ... 
CategoryC | *blank* | *blank* | *blank* | ... 
...
```

**DataTableB**

```
CategoryA   | *blank* | *blank* | *blank* | ... 
Jessica ____| _35  __ | _35 _   | _ 35_   | ... 
CategoryB   | *blank* | *blank* | *blank* | ... 
Michaela  __| _10  __ | _11 _   | _ 12_   | ... 
Miranda   __| 25   __ | _25 _   | _ 25_   | ... 
CategoryC   | *blank* | *blank* | *blank* | ... 
...
```

Now I need to combine them and the final product has to be like:

**DataTableC**

```
CategoryA   | *blank* | *blank* | *blank* | ... 
Michael   __| 24  __  | _31 _   | _ 21_   | ... 
Tony    ____| _29  __ | _28 _   | _ 19_   | ... 
Jessica ____| _35  __ | _35 _   | _ 35_   | ... 
CategoryB   | *blank* | *blank* | *blank* | ... 
John ____   | _12  __ | _31 _   | _ 25_   | ... 
Michaela __ | _10  __ | _11 _   | _ 12_   | ... 
Miranda __  | 25  __  | _25 _   | _ 25_   | ... 
CategoryC   | *blank* | *blank* | *blank* | ...
```

As you can see, the data from DataTableB has to come after the data of DataTableA.
Also, the category rows shouldn't be duplicated.

I got them merged using DataTable.Merge() method, but now it looks like two DataTables just combined back to back, and it has the duplicate category rows too.
I am wanting to use .Join method somehow, to sort them and put data together, but I am not quite sure how to go about it.

I thought about using loops too, adding a row at a time into a DataTable object, but this is cumbersome, and I thought there should be an easier way than that.
Could someone give me advice?

Comment: This should be simple using LINQ 2 DataSet.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/linq-to-dataset  If you get stuck, post sample code in this question to reproduce the input DataTables and desired results.

Comment: If you format those things as code blocks they would get a lot nicer looking. To format text as code either prefix the line with 4 spaces, surround the block with 3 backticks on their own line top and bottom, or click drag highlight it and click the `{}` code button above the text editor

Comment: Join doesn't Union; Union causes the number of rows to increase, Join causes the number of columns to increase - two very different things. If your DataTables really do contain an empty row saying "category" and then every row "after" it is "that category" until you hit the next "category" row, then your data modelling is really messed up; datatables/db tables do not work this way at all. Rows are an unordered set of data. If a row belongs in a particular category then that category is specified in a column of the row, on every row. "Category C" may hence be repeated over and over again.

Comment: The final reporting tool might group a display like this (some kind of crosstabulation or drilldown), but it should not be the responsibility of any data container along the way to maintain this curious presentation as a factor of the order of/values of rows

Answer (score 1):

Per my concerns noted in the comments if you're stuck with this data how it is (and if you aren't, please change it now, before you start piling more code on top of this shaky foundation) then you'll need to implement some custom merging (this is an example of why I'm saying "don't do this, because this poor data structure is causing you enough headaches already that you've had to come on SO and ask about it") along the lines of:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>();
string currentCat = "Category A";

FillDictionaryFromDataTable(d, table1);
FillDictionaryFromDataTable(d, table2);


public void FillDictionaryFromDataTable(Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> d, DataTable dt) {

  foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows){

    string x = r[0].ToString();
    if(x.StartsWith("Category"))
      currentCat = x;
    else {
      if(!d.ContainsKey(currentCat))
        d[currentCat] = new List<DataRow>();

      d[currentCat].Add(r);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you have a Dictionary of Lists of DataRow. You can't add these rows to a new table beacuse they already belong in a table; you need to clone them

```
DataTable x = table1.Clone();//make structure but not data
foreach(string key in d.Keys.OrderBy(k => k)){

  var catRo = x.NewRow();
  catRo[0] = key;
  x.Rows.Add(catRo);

  foreach(DataRow ro in d[key]) //a List<Datarow>
    x.Rows.Add(ro.ItemArray); //make a new row that clones this row's values
}
```

Yuck